# Lightning Datatable :: Enable Editing without inline editing

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-datatable

I have an LWC component which uses lightning Datatable i.e., Edit Values(A). This is embedded in Read Only mode in an Aura component which we display on the Opportunity object.

There is inline editing enabled when you click on Edit Values(A), it opens a pop up where you can inline edit each cell in the table. However it requires to click each cell (the pencil icon) or double click it.

How can I enable the LWC component to show all cells editable as soon as the pop up opens , so there is no need to click Pencil icon or double click it. The values can be calculated when I click on the save button.

Thanks a lot for your help .